# DropDownListFor selection not being saved

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC.  I am using a DropDownListFor to display a list of company names and, based on the selection made, filling in other Customer fields. The customer fields are being populated fine, but when I attempt to POST the record, I get a validation error "Company name is required", even though the company name has been selected in the DropDownListFor.   Here is the ViewModel:

```
     namespace CMSUsersAndRoles.Models
{
    public class QuoteViewModel
    {   [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Quote Id")]
        public int QuoteId { get; set; }
        // Columns from Customer table
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a company")]
        [Display(Name = "Customer Id")]
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Sales Rep")]
        public string SalesRep { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address 1")]
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        [StringLength(10)]
        [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Work Phone")]
        public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Cell Phone")]
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Range(0, 100)]
        public decimal? Discount { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Payment Terms")]
        public int? PaymentTerms { get; set; }
        // Columns from QuoteDetail table
        [Display(Name = "Quote Detail")]
        public List<QuoteDetail> QuoteDetail { get; set; }
        // Columns from Quote table


        public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
        public decimal Tax { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Quote Date")]
        public DateTime? QuoteDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Good Until")]
        public DateTime? GoodUntil { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Quote Sent")]
        public DateTime? QuoteSent { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Approved")]
        public DateTime? DateApproved { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Ordered")]
        public DateTime? DateOrdered { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is the code from the View:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Customers, "CustomerId", "Company"), "---Select one---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "company" } });
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Company)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Here is the Get:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            QuoteViewModel qvm = new QuoteViewModel();

            var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
            ViewBag.Customers = customers;

            return View(qvm);
        }
```

And here is the code for the POST:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(QuoteViewModel qvm)
{

if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
                Quote quote1 = new Quote();

                quote1.CustomerId = qvm.CustomerId;
                ...
                customer.CustomerId = (int)qvm.CustomerId;
                ...
                customer.Company = qvm.Company;    

                db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                try
                    {
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                    {

                        var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
                        // Get failed entry
                        var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                        // Now call refresh on ObjectContext
                        objContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, entry.Entity);


                    }


                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
            ViewBag.Customers = customers;

            return View(qvm);
        }
```

What am I missing?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Company name has not been selected - all that being selected is a value for `CustomerId ` (which is what your dropdownlist is binding to). You have not shown us the relevant code.

Comment: And your `customer.Company = qvm.Company;` line of code in the POST method suggests your view model has a property `Company Company` - view models so not contain properties which are data models.

Comment: What code do you need to see?

Comment: All the code in your view model

Comment: Code posted above.

Comment: Your controller code has `customer.Company = qvm.Company;`where `qvm` is `QuoteViewModel`,  but the view model you have shown us does not contain a property named `Company` so you code would not even compile. You have not shown us the correct code.

Comment: Corrected code above.

Comment: You have still not shown the correct code. Your edit just adds `public string Company { get; set; }` but that does not have a `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: And why are you modifying `Customer`? Your creating/editing a `Quote`, not its `Customer`. Your `db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;` line of code makes no sense.

Comment: I had the [Required] attribute on the Customers data model, but not on the ViewModel.  I've now added it to the ViewModel above.  I'm allowing the user to edit Customer fields (perhaps a different address) if they wish.  Really not sure if I should have allowed this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140123/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dwight-mendoza).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not setting the value of the HiddenFor below.  Thanks, @StephenMuecke.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Company)
```